# When I start my spring boot application, my database is not initiating

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have one spring-boot test application in which I provide the following configuration in application.yml file. when I start my server using mvn test, it doesn't initiate the database connection, what can be the issue here? Am I missing any dependency in pom.xml?

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:db2://<fullURL>
spring.datasource.username = <uname>
spring.datasource.password = <password>
```

Following are my dependencies related to spring-boot

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

Here are my boot logs in which I don't see the database connection logs

```
[INFO] Running com.test.installments.customers.data.processor.test.RunTest
11:11:30.823 [main] INFO  o.s.b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.test.in
stallments.customers.data.processor.test.RunTest], using SpringBootContextLoader
11:11:30.829 [main] INFO  o.s.t.c.s.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.test.installments.customers.data.
processor.test.RunTest]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
11:11:30.976 [main] INFO  o.s.b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]:
 [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springfr
amework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecut
ionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.we
b.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener, org.springframe
work.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.te
st.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.tes
t.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.co
ntext.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener]
11:11:30.992 [main] INFO  o.s.b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBefor
eModesTestExecutionListener@162be91c, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener@2488b073, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mo
ckito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@1c9f0a20, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@55787112, org.springfra
mework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@1cd201a8, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@7db82169,
 org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@1992eaf4, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener@f74e83
5, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@3276732, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionLi
stener@3f28bd56, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@31e3250d, org.springframework.boot.test.aut
oconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@19fe4644, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListe
ner@21d8bcbe, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener@5be067de]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.3)

11:11:31.362 [main] INFO  c.m.i.c.data.processor.test.RunTest - Starting RunTest using Java 11.0.8 on test with PID 17676 (started by test in C:\git\c
ustomers-data-processor-tests)
11:11:31.362 [main] INFO  c.m.i.c.data.processor.test.RunTest - The following profiles are active: dev
11:11:31.446 [main] INFO  c.m.i.c.data.processor.test.RunTest - Started RunTest in 0.422 seconds (JVM running for 1.403)
-----------Databse driver name---------- com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
11:11:32.161 [main] DEBUG com.intuit.karate.Suite - [config] classpath:karate-config.js
11:11:32.858 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - karate.env system property was: null
11:11:32.932 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] Total number of rows
---------------------------------------------------------
feature: classpath:com/test/installments/customers/data/processor/test/fileuload/uploadfile.feature
```

Comment: which database you are trying to connect with spring boot ?

Comment: Tried to connect db2, but then also tried to connect oracle, but neither of them worked.

Comment: You didn't show anywhere that tried to talk to the database. If you are using a typical pool setup, your pool won't create connections until they're needed. (Note also that you shouldn't be specifying versions of Spring dependencies; those are managed, and you can introduce incompatibilities. You're receiving warnings and should pay attention to them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things I note:

1. You are mentioning `application.yml` but the format of the file is properties
2. You need to add the Driver in your dependencies for Spring Boot to pick up as well.
3. If you are running test, and have an `applicatio.yml` in `src/test/resources`, it will override the one in `src/main/resources`